# SQL-Update ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, sql, vb.net, formview

I am pretty new to asp.net. I made this update sql statement:

```
Dim dbconn As SqlConnection
    Dim dbcomm As SqlCommand


    dbconn = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sqlString"))
    dbconn.Open()

    Dim updateCmd As String = "UPDATE tbl_Project SET ID = @ID," _
     & " Titel = @Titel, CatID = @CatID, Website = @Website," _
     & " Naslag = @Naslag; WHERE ID = @ID;"

    dbcomm = New SqlCommand(updateCmd, _
     dbconn)
    dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int))
    dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Titel", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar))
    dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CatID", _
       SqlDbType.Int))
    dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Website", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar))
    dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Naslag", _
       SqlDbType.VarChar))
    dbcomm = New SqlCommand(updateCmd, dbconn)
    dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()`
```

I have this all set-up in a Forview Edit mode. The idea is that when you search for a record and click on`details` it will brgin you to the editable project view. From the details page you can edit it and update the project.

***problem***

When I click the Update button it says: Declare the variable @ID which I have. And I have no clue of what I am doing wrong.

Here is my Formview:

```
            <table class="style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="kopje" Text="Categorie"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="kopje" Text="Klant">        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style4">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="kopje        " Text="Website"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" CssClass="kopje" Text="Titel">        </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownCat" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDrop" DataTextField="Categorie" 
                            DataValueField="Cat_ID" value="0">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDrop" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Goed %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_Cat]">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Decimal" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceKlant" DataTextField="Bedrijf" 
                            DataValueField="Klant_ID">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceKlant" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Goed %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_Klant]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxWebsite" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Website") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTitel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Titel") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="TextBoxOmschrijving" runat="server" CssClass="kopje" 
                            Text="Omschrijving"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="style4">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxslag" runat="server" Height="200px" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Naslag") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="style4">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 

CausesValidation="True" 
  CssClass="buttons" Text="Update"
  OnClientClick="Verzend"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style3">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="style4">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `AddWithValue`.  You need to specify the value of `@ID`

```
dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "TheValue");
dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", "TitelValue");
```

Comment: Then it says: Argement not specified for parameter "value" 
Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @DiederikEEn - Did you forget to include `value` in your update command?

Comment: Well I have this :`bcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 153
        dbcomm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Titel", _
           SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBoxTitel.Text` but for some reasons It doesnt recognize the textboxes

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon `(;)` that shouldn't be there after

`"@Naslag" in your SQL-command (" Naslag = @Naslag**;** WHERE ID = @ID;")`. Could be enough to cause you that error.

Comment: You haven't included the opening tag for the formview in the code. And probably not the main sqldatasource. You should have the "ID" in the DataKeyNames-attribute of the formview. And you have a querystring parameter for the category drop down. Is that correct?

Comment: Think you might need to check this page on how to use the form view: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227970(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yes that is correct, I set The DataKeyNames to ID But it doesnt fix the problem of not finding the the value of TextBoxTitel.Text any clue on that?

Comment: As you see in the "edititemplate"-tag in the link above, you should use Bind instead of Eval. Eval is only for displaying. But I believe you have more problems than that. You should mimic the code in that link, with the update statement in the datasource and all.

Answer (score 0):

kindly make following change in your code

```
         SqlCommand _cmd = _con.CreateCommand();
        _cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_Project SET ID = @ID," _
         & " Titel = @Titel, CatID = @CatID, Website = @Website," _
         & " Naslag = @Naslag WHERE ID = @ID";
        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", '1'));
        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Titel", 'title'));
        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CatID", '1'));
        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Website", 'www.google.com'));
        _cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Naslag", 'Naslag'));
        if (_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            return "Record Successfully Updated";
        else
            return "Record not Affected to DataBase";
```

Comment: Yes - and that overload of `.Add` is obsolete and has been replaced with `AddWithValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some mistakes in your code, the correct code should be

```
Dim updateCmd As String = "UPDATE tbl_Project SET ID = @ID, Titel = @Titel, CatID = @CatID, Website = @Website, Naslag = @Naslag WHERE ID = @ID"
dbcomm = New SqlCommand(updateCmd, dbconn)
dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", value)
dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", value)
dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatID", value)
.........
.........
// remove this-> dbcomm = New SqlCommand(updateCmd, dbconn)
dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```